# How to reference multiple objectForKey at one time?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have loaded several images into a view and set states for different objects. I would like to remove multiple objects at one time. How can I reference PC20 and PC21 and others with less code?

Currently I have this, but I assume there is a way to call out several Objectforkeys at once and set the state.

```
{
 TransformViewP *state = [states objectForKey:@"PC20"];
 [state removeFromSuperview];
  state = nil;
}
{
 TransformViewP *state = [states objectForKey:@"PC21"];
 [state removeFromSuperview];
  state = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use a list of keys and a loop

```
NSArray<NSString*>* statesToRemove = @[@"PC20",@"PC21"]; // Can keep adding more keys if you want
for(NSString* stateKey in statesToRemove)
{
   TransformViewP *state = [states objectForKey:stateKey];
   [state removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Also you do not need to explicitly state `state = nil;` because once you leave those curly braces that scope is left and state will be destroyed.